# How to upgrade Scala to a newer version from the command line?

Tags: scala, sbt

Is there away to upgrade the installed Scala version via sbt / other command line tool?

I'm sure there is a way, but I couldn't find any after a quick search, am I missing anything?

Comment: This is generally operating system dependent.  What platform are you on?

Comment: Windows (but also Mac / Linux at times). I was hoping for a magical `$ scala --update` feature :) I assume from the question it's not going to be that easy...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Each SBT project specifies the version of Scala to use to compile and run its code. It defaults to being the version of Scala that SBT uses internally, but is always overridable.

E.g.

```
  scalaVersion := "2.10.0"
```

As Connor Doyle mentioned, if your OS has a package system that includes Scala (some Linux distros I know of do) and you are, for some reason obligated to use that, you are pretty much at their mercy to provide a new version on a timely basis. The [Scala Web Site](https://www.scala-lang.org/) ([downloads here](https://www.scala-lang.org/download/)) provides a variety of installers and tarballs / Zip archives for every release they've made.

Mac OS X users can use [HomeBrew](https://brew.sh) to get up-to-date SBT and Scala.

Comment: Indeed, setting `scalaVersion` is an easy way to get test out a new version before you commit to upgrading.  You can even access the REPL by doing `sbt console` from the project directory.

Answer (score 4):

To set the project version temporarily from the command line:

```
++ 2.10.4
```

To set the project version permanently from the command line:

```
set scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
session save
```

Answer (score 3):

I just executed one command line"homebrew remove scala;homebrew install scala" to update to the latest version. Isn't this enought?

I also found this link (http://wkmacura.tumblr.com/post/11577309978/installing-specific-versions-with-homebrew) and hope it works for you.